# Test if a port is listening without try/catch

Tags: c#, .net

If I've got a TCP port on my "server" app that will be listening within a few seconds (i.e. I launch my client and server apps at the same time), I know on my client app I can do (simplistically)

```
TcpClient Connect() {
  try {
    return new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 30276);
  } catch {
    Connect();
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without throwing exceptions though?  It's inconvenient to have these in logs and stopping the debugger all the time, and just feels like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4bdbdca-6286-4815-9847-8fab0731a1ab/tryconnect-tcpclientconnect-that-doesnt-throws-exception-it-returns-bool?forum=netfxnetcom) is what you're looking for

Comment: You may check for the [Connected Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if that's what you're looking for? Not really sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: Just ping it :  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/109427/How-to-PING-Server-in-C

Comment: Perhaps look into TcpClient.BeginConnect()?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145193(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: One way or another, you **MUST** always be prepared to handle exceptions. Even if the remote server is up and running, your connect could fail. You need to be able to handle that gracefully. I would not personally use _recursion_ as a way of dealing with retries (a loop makes more sense), but otherwise you're going to wind up with _something_ that works similarly: makes the attempt, retry (possibly some finite number of times) on failure.

Comment: Note that regardless you should handle only _expected_ exception (i.e. `IOException`), not _all_ exceptions. You can configure the debugger to not break on handled exceptions (indeed, this is generally the default).

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes, as stated, the code is a simplistic example.  Those points do not address the question at hand.